# thycotic integration with gitlab CI job

Tags: gitlab-ci

We use thycotic to manage the secrets.
I want to access thycotic secrets in the gitlab ci yaml file.

While referring the docs, gitlab supports the Hashicorp vault to store the secrets and access them in gitlab CI job.

Same way: I need it for Thycotic

Is it possible?

Answer (score 1):

This is currently not supported, but actively requested in [`gitlab-org/gitlab` issues 291072](https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab/-/issues/291072)

Only alternative, not yet released:

> We will soon release an upgraded CI_JOB_JWT token that should support various hyperclouds, including their secrets managers.
>
> If one can use a JWT token to authenticate with Tycothic, I'd recommend to go in this direction.
> Could you check for me of OpenID Connect is an option for Tycothic?

But:

> Thycotic does have OIDC support (among others) for their dsv product, but not the on-premises one

Comment: ok Thanks. I see they don't even support AWS secret manager. Is it true ?

Comment: @user2315104 it appears so: https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab/-/issues/225549, https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab/-/issues/336300

Comment: But i think it is not released yet

Comment: @user2315104 Yes, I meant: "it appears so, that they do *not* support yet AWS secret manager". Hence the two issues, which are not yet resolved, to illustrate the current lack of support for that feature.